# Tenho o id do estado e da cidade, e agora?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-select

Olá, em um site de classificados com PHP e MySQL fiz através do Ajax a inserção do estado e da cidade. Ao selecionar o estado é passado o `id` e ele envia para o arquivo **getcidade.php** que faz o `select` e retorna a cidade respectiva, assim inserindo no banco os ID's.

```
TABELA tb_estado CAMPOS id|int e uf|varchar(2)
TABELA tb_cidade CAMPOS id|int e id_estado_fk|int e cidade|varchar(100)
```

Porém agora no banco esta o `id` do estado 26 e o da cidade 4773 como exibir o nome do estado SP e a cidade Bauru?

NOTA* Eu já faço um `INNER JOIN` com o id do usuário para exibir a cidade/estado que o fulano cadastrou, porém fica no anúncio.

```
TABELA tb_anuncio CAMPOS id|int e id_usuario_fk|int e estado_fk|int(10) e cidade_fk|int(10)
```

Na página fica assim: Inserido **em: 23/08 Local: 4773/26**

Como posso pegar os nomes na tabela?

Comment: Igor, você pode incluir na pergunta o `SELECT` que está fazendo para pegar esses dados? Obrigado.

Comment: Igor, edite sua pergunta com o design das tabelas e edite também o titulo ele não tem sentido nenhum.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 2):

Considerando essas tabelas criadas de acordo, aparentemente, com sua estrutura teríamos isso:

#### Tabela Anúncio

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_anuncio`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_anuncio` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `anuncio` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `id_cidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

#### Tabela Cidade

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_cidade`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_cidade` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

#### Tabela Estado

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tb_estado`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_estado` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Então o `select` com o `join` tanto para a `tb_cidade` quanto para o `tb_estado` ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT a.anuncio, c.name cidade, e.nome estado 
FROM tb_anuncio a 
JOIN tb_cidade c ON a.id_cidade = c.id 
JOIN tb_estado e ON a.id_estado = e.id
```

#### Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pergunta confusa, o SELECT ideal para isso seria:

```
"SELECT tb_estado.uf, tb_cidade.cidade from tb_estado, tb_cidade 
 where tb_cidade.id_estado_fk = tb_estado.id";
```

ai você acrescenta o que quizer.